# How to understand the hits per second and active thread over time graphs in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Can anyone please suggest me, how to analyse the generated hits per second and active thread over time graphs
[image: hits per second]

[image: active threads over time]

Answer (score 0):

I believe they are self-explanatory.

If you want analysis like how it impacted the application/application server under test, you have to monitor the server resources of that time and for the application, you can try to access/use it manually and/or using ui/api automation to know how the application is behaving (e.g. working or not, response time has increased or not, etc).

Below articles would provide you and idea regarding what/how to analyze performance test results:

[Interpreting Performance Test Results](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/the-art-of/9780596155858/ch04.html)

[How to Interpret and Report Your Performance Test Results](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-interpret-and-report-your-performance-test)

Answer (score 0):

Hits per second during test run is live graph where you can view number of requests sent to server per second and once test gets end, you can calculate throughput.

If you apply Steady load pattern and observe any drop in hits per second, then you need to review number of users running and response time to understand reason of drop.